# How to do imports in Typescript without breaking IntelliSense?

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using webpack to compile my Typescript and the following thing happens:

When I do an import like `import User, { IUser, IUserInput } from 'models/User';`, the autocomplete in IntelliSense works fine. However when I compile I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./lib/services/users.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'models/User' in '/Users/<>/lib/services'
 @ ./lib/services/users.ts 49:0-31 56:38-42 113:49-53 135:49-53 160:46-50 174:49-53 177:46-50 211:38-42
 @ ./lib/controllers/users.ts
 @ ./lib/app.js
```

When I do an import like `import User, { IUser, IUserInput } from 'models/User.ts';`, it compiles fine but IntelliSense unfortunately does not work. It shows a redline with:

```
An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension. Consider importing '../controllers/users' instead.ts(2691)
```

I want to be able to compile and have intelisense working. The way I do the imports does not really bother me. Below are the Webpack and Typescript configs. Any thing I can do in there?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    // "js": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./lib",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
}
```

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    js: './lib/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: './app.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
  },
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'eval',
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true,
  },
  externals: {
    sharp: 'commonjs sharp',
    uws: 'uws',
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi, do you use Visual Studio code or Visual Studio?  Maybe similar issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616272/an-import-path-cannot-end-with-ts-nodejs-and-visual-code), but it seems to be more related to vs code.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Hi, I'm using VS Code! And I saw that question already, but it didn't resolve it for me.

Comment: Hi, maybe this free extension makes some help. And there's discussion on github for this, you can find it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16577) :)